# Perf doesn't add up to 100%

Tags: android, linux, profiling, perf

I am trying to measure the cpu usage of my Android mobile phone using perf tool. Since my phone (Redmi Note 3) doesn't have perf tool. I used simpleperf tool provided by google. I recorded system wide cpu usage using `perf record -e cpu-cycles -a`. The cpu usage overhead reported by perf must add to 100% but cpu usage report I got from my phone only adds up to 12% after 10 minutes of profiling. I profiled while putting my phone on idle with all applications killed.

And also when I profiled for 1 minute it added to about 70%.

Is it abnormal? or doesn't perf report idle time of cpu so I only have 12% of cpu usage left?

Comment: The `cpu-cycles` event isn't happening when the clock is stopped (i.e. while the CPU is sleeping in low-power idle).  How did you calculate 100%, anyway?  Are you assuming that the CPU would run at max clock speed all the time?

Comment: Perf calculates the overhead of each function so 100% doesn't necessarily mean 100% cpu usage. It was written in man page Bellow that it must add to 100% all the time as it shows "relative" percentages http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-report.1.html

Comment: Oh right, you're using record/report.  I was thinking `perf stat`, where you get a single total for the whole measurement period for each event.  Try `perf stat report` to get a stat-like report from your data file.  Oh, I just tried and that only works with `perf stat record`, not with regular `perf record`.

Comment: Anyway, try `perf stat` as a sanity check to see what the total clocks over an interval should be, even if you can't get that in the same run as `perf record`.

Comment: I need cpu overheads for some specific functions, that is why I using perf record/report. But I am not sure if the profiled data is correct as it is not adding up to 100%. I tried perf stat just now, it is not showing function overhead but 100% cpu. I will try to do it for 10 min and see if it is showing 12% as well.

Comment: Right, `perf stat` doesn't try to track the location of each event, only the total.  I was suggesting separate runs of the same thing with `perf stat` and `perf record` to see if `record` is getting as many counts.  Stat isn't percentage-based, so try `perf report --show-nr-samples` to show the actual number of samples as well / instead of percents.

Comment: Hey, I ran perf stat along with perf record and cpu cycles where almost same one shows 13.6 billion while other shows 13.9 but still I got only 52% total sum. But when I ran perf record for just 1 sec I got about 100% total sum (100.01 to be exact)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that it is because of floating point (precision) error in perf. Since perf only calculates overhead upto `0.0x%` percision when I run perf record for long enough even with overhead less than 0.01% pile up and after 30 min they add upto about 50% so the overhead reported will only sum up to 50% as rest 50% is from `0.00x%` which is rounded down to 0.00%.